# Symfony 2 insert cyrillic in database

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

Recently, I encountered some problems while I try to insert some Russian Cyrillic text in a database. I'm on the framework symfony2, I'm using Doctrine ORM and a Nginx web server. The database is a PostgreSql. The problem happens sometimes when I try to insert a russian text in a column, I get a 500 Internal Server Error with this message :

```
SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERREUR: invalid byte sequence for encoding « UTF8 » : 0xd1
```

And the most weird is that happens in a column and not an other with the same string... My php files and DB are encoding correctly in UTF8.

Is there somebody already encountered the same problem and achieve to solve it ? Thanks a lot for the help.

The \l request from psql show an encoding UTF8 and Collate and Ctype fr_FR.UTF-8

```
server_encoding UTF8

client_encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on what is showed, If that error is only in one column with the same string of another that works I think you need to be sure that the column that gives the error have the correct collation because the problem is surely related to `Character not in repertoire: 7 ERREUR: invalid byte sequence for encoding « UTF8 » : 0xd1` due to `Ctype fr_FR.UTF-8` because the byte range of `fr_FR` is different from cyrillic.

I manage cyrillic chars in my mysql db with all the tables/collations encoded with **utf-8 unicode** (or general).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If i want to change collation I have to create a new db, is it right ? However, I can insert cyrillic characters using a SQL request... so maybe the problem come from symfony ?

Comment: If that table is the unique to have "Ctype fr_FR.UTF-8" is sufficient apply the changing only to that, otherwise is better to migrate all data to a new db with the right params. If I remember well and well understand what you need you can use cyrillic without to take care to encode it before insert in SQL Req. I used cyrillic also in the routes without any problem (there are only some tips to take care)